# Why is my SpriteKit update() function creating multiple NSTimers?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a SpriteKit game that updates based on the amount of time passed. The game spawns enemies using an `NSTimer` and its `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` method, calling the `spawnEnemy` function every 2.0 seconds.

When 5 seconds have passed there should be a very brief intermission, preventing new enemies from spawning in order to show a level change animation.

When the initial 5 seconds has been reached, everything works well up until the conditional where `self.nextLevelDelayTicker == 100`. Once this conditional is met, the `"YOLO"` string is only fired once in the console. However, I'm assuming multiple instances of `NSTimer` are being created and stored within `self.timer` since a massive amount of enemies are spawned after `self.resumeGame()` is called to create a new scheduled timer.

Any ideas on why this is happening even though I have flags set up within my conditional to only call the `self.resumeGame()` function once?

```
func resumeGame() {
    // Start game timer
    // Need a way to access ib action of pause button
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "spawnEnemy", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if gameTicker.isActive == true {
        gameTicker.increment()
    }

    // If gameTicker is equal to 5 seconds, increase enemy amount
    if gameTicker.getTimePassed() % 500 == 0 {
        self.enemyAmount += 1
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        levelCount += 1

        gameTicker.isActive = false
    }

    // If level has been completed and last ghost has been killed, activate next level scene
    if gameTicker.isActive == false && enemyArray.count == 0 {
        self.nextLevelDelayTicker.increment()

        if self.nextLevelDelayTicker.getTimePassed() == 100 {
            print("YOLO")
            self.gameTicker.isActive = true
            self.nextLevelDelayTicker.reset()
            self.resumeGame()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer below is worthy of consideration, but as far as your question is concerned, you created your timer variable and placed in the update. Every time update gets called a new timer gets created and hence the idea of multiple timers although the below answer is good, I like to use skaction and create my timers there and call them in appropriate variables rather than in update method. But that's just me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to follow your code.. but I think your approach here isn't great for spritekit.  It's probably making things way more complicated than it needs to be.

You can keep track of time using your update method directly.  It would probably be worth rewriting this part of your code.  Would work better within spritekit and be less prone to bugs.

All you really need is delta time.

**scene properties**

```
// time values
var delta = NSTimeInterval(0)
var last_update_time = NSTimeInterval(0)

// some time youre trying to keep track of
var timeLimit = NSTimeInterval(5)
var timeLimitMax = NSTimeInterval(5)
```

**your scene's update method**

```
 func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        if last_update_time == 0.0 {
            delta = 0
        } else {
            delta = currentTime - last_update_time
        }

        last_update_date = currentTime

        // now we can keep track of time
        timeLimit -= self.delta
        if timeLimit <= 0 {
            // do something and reset timer
            timeLimit = timeLimitMax
        }
}
```

Now if you're going to be consistently spawning something every number of seconds then we dont even need to bother with `update` to do this.  Just put this in your `viewDidLoad`

Now we're running this code every two seconds forever.  The best part is this will pause and resume with your game automatically.  You don't have to manage SKAction too much.  spritekit does it for you :)

```
let spawnAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(
    SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.waitForDuration(2),
        SKAction.runBlock({
            [unowned self] in
            self.spawnEnemy()   
        })
    ])
)
runAction(spawnAction)
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because that's the way to go in SpriteKit, but you should slightly change the spawnAction. First, you need explicit self inside of a block in order to compile. Second, it will create strong reference cycle and the scene will never be deallocated after transition to the next scene, because self is captured and action is endless. So before transition, either removing the action explicitly, or using capture list inside of a block (unowned self) will solve the issue.

Comment: good point..  i wrote this code without xcode so im sure its not 100% perfect.  i will edit.

Comment: Pretty good answer in regards to spawning enemies based on a timer. I got rid of all of my `NSTimer`s, and replaced them with one SKAction. The pause/resume functionality works like a charm now. One thing though, I need to be able to pause the `spawnAction` SKAction every 15 seconds for 5 seconds, in order to show an animation and prevent enemies from spawning during that time. Once that 5 second delay is up, I need to be able to reactivate the `SKAction`. Is there a pause `SKAction` method available?

Comment: Would I just hardcode ~7 more `SKAction.waitForDuraction(2)`s into the `SKAction.repeatActionForever`, then add a `SKAction.waitForDuraction(5)` at the very end? It should be noted that the 5 second delay for the animation should only be activated once all enemies have been killed / removed from the scene.

Comment: I read what you wrote a few times and don't really follow what you're trying to do. However once it gets complicated like this I tend to start using update and ditch skaction. Skaction is great when you're doing a one off type of thing.. But once it's set you can't modify it.  You can only cancel it and make a new one.  If there's logic and changing conditions involved probably better to use update at that point

Comment: @10000RubyPools You can assign a key to a certain action, and later in your code , you can use that key to access the action associated with it(and pause it)... But you should ask another question if you don't know to do it, because this answer already solves your original issue related to the amount of spawned nodes...